# Get product collection with product ids

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Is it possible to get a product collection bassd on array of product ids?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given an instantiated but not loaded **collection** `$collection` and an array of product ids `$productIds`, you can use `addIdFilter()` just as in Magento 1:

```
$collection->addIdFilter($productIds);
```

To instantiate a collection, you can inject a `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` and then use

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
```

---

**But this is not recommended practice anymore!**

---

In Magento 2, you should not think too much in terms of collections anymore when using core modules, they are a mere implementation detail. Use the service contracts instead:

- Inject `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` and `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder`
- `use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;`
- Build a search criteria and pass it to `$productRepository->getList()`:

  ```
  $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(new Filter([
      Filter::KEY_FIELD => 'entity_id',
      Filter::KEY_CONDITION_TYPE => 'in',
      Filter::KEY_VALUE => $productIds
  ]))->create();
  $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
  ```

  `$products` then is an array of products.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but using repositories doesn't seem to allow full control on the result; for example: how do you add an attribute to EAV entities? Or join an external table? In that case I still see Magento2 core uses collections. Is there a valid alternative? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. There are often cases where you still need collections. See also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158098/243

Comment: Exactly my problem now. I built a working method to get a result with repository and the result could not be modified (or even put into a collection neatly, missing add/set data methods... and many other issues).

Answer (score 11):

Use SearchCriteria and Product Repositories:

```
$productIds = [.....];
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilter('entity_id', $productIds, 'in')
                ->create();

$products = $this->productRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

To get search criteria builder and product repository object you have to require:

- Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
- Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface

Comment: I want to get the product collection from my entity ids, Please give me full code or idea!

Answer (score 1):

```
$porductIds=array(2,6,7);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $collectionByIds = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collectionByIds->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $data));
    $collectionByIds->load();

    foreach ($collectionByIds as $collection) :
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getName());
    endforeach;
```