# How to get all product details using multiple product id/sku in array REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need one help. I need to get all product details using multiple product `id/sku` in array using `REST API`. I am explaining my code below.

```
$pid=[23,24,25]
foreach ($pid as $v) {
        $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=".$v);


        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        $resup = json_decode($resp, 1);
        $allProdArr[]=$resup;
    }
```

Here I am using loop for that reason also the response is coming late. Here I need Is there any `REST API` which can take the direct  array of `ids/sku` and give the response in a single request. By using loop and calling passing the request each time give the late response which is not user friendly. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
    $pids=[23,24,25]
    $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=".implode(',',$pids));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    $resup = json_decode($resp, 1);
    $allProdArr[]=$resup;
```

Comment: OK i will test and let you know.

Comment: I tested it  and issue is its ignoring the 1st value of array and also if array has only one value it did not give any response.

Comment: I have modified the code and it is working perfectly as tested.

Comment: Ok,its working but one thing missing here `i.e- stock count(['stock_item']['qty'])`. This part is not coming.

Comment: To get stock information you have to call stock related api by sku.

Comment: Can I please have that end point api ?

Comment: endpoint is /V1/stockItems/[sku]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82768/discussion-between-satya-and-prasanta-hatui).

Answer (score 0):

This approach can help in your case, just go through detail of this article: [Get product collection with product ids](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112009/get-product-collection-with-product-ids)

Comment: But this is not `REST API` implementation.

Comment: Above article would help you to get desired data for your use case. After that just go through this article to implement as REST API perfectly. https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-start-with-magento-2-api/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your array in **searchCriteria** value and add the condition to check if **entity_id** is in your array or not.

Try the following code.

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
$ids = '['.implode(',', $ids).']';
$restResourceUri = "http://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=$ids&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in";
```